# Maintain the size of an integer in php

Tags: php

i need to save into database some integer values like '09'.This value comes from a form of my website.
The database only save '9' and ignore the '0' in front. However i need the full length (size) because i need to generate some Member Code for the users of my site.
Any ideas please ?

Comment: Save it as a string. If you need `09` to be intact then that no longer behaves as a number

Comment: Hint: Integers do not have leading zeroes. Strings do.

Comment: You're also going to run into problems with leading zeroes being interpreted as octal

Comment: Better to store it as `9`, and only add leading zeroes when you need to display/output it

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I finaly used to save it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

I have one idea to store leading zero's on your `INT` field. If your are using `mysql` database then try restructure your existing INT field to **column_name INT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL** and then store integer with preceding zeros.

```
`column_name` INT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL
```

**OR**

If you just want to display/output it then just insert the `INT` as you're doing and make Left Padding with leading Zeros like

```
SELECT LPAD( your_integer_number, your_integer_number_length, 'fill_number') AS Member_Code;
```

See [LPAD()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, please take this notes:

Saving data:
1- get it as a string from the form

2- in case of using numeric only make a java script validation to refuse if the field contains non numeric characters.

3- in DB make its Column a string type to save it as it is.

Loading data later:
- Tail any select query that will bring a list of this column with Order by a convert to Int for this column (just in case of using numeric only to be saved).

PS: that for best ordering numerically if no leading zero exist.

If you'd like any further help in code don't hesitate to send.